# Как избавиться от <div class="help-block">Поле обязательно....</div> в GridView Yii2

Tags: yii2

В модели я прописал правила валидации

```
  public function rules()
  {
    return [
        ...         
        ['username','required', 'message' => Yii::t('app','fio_requared')],
        ['phone','required', 'message' => Yii::t('app','phone_requared')],
        ...
        ];
    }
```

Этим правилам прописал message. Он работает при создании, редактировании формы, всё хорошо. Но GridView автоматически генерирует этот message в

```
 <div class="help-block">Поле обязательно....</div>
```

и отображает мне его в шапке таблицы вот так
[image: лишние данные]
Как мне избавиться от генерации этого поля в шапке таблицы?

Comment: **requared** выделенное жирным ни чего не напоминает?

Comment: Так это поле обязательное для заполнения в форме. Но это ж не форма. Это табла содержащая созданные ранее элементы формы

Comment: **Так это поле обязательное для заполнения в форме** **Но это ж не форма** А что же это по вашему как не форма? а как сверстана(таблицы\блоки\...) - дело десятое =)

Comment: сообщения от которых мне надо избавиться должны появляться в тот момент, когда человек не ввёл при создании(!) или редактировании(!) объекта информацию в указанные поля. Тут верно. Но под пустыми инпутами, которые предназначены для фильтрации (а именно их я показал на картинке) в общей таблице уже созданных объектов этих сообщений быть не должно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для gridView в качестве filterModel нужно указать не саму модель а ее наследника SearchModel в которой переопределены правила валидации. Для типичного примера можно сгенерировать crud твоей модели через генератор GII.